# How to implement previous-command-scroll in a standalone shell program?

Tags: c, linux

For a class project we have to implement a basic Linux shell. As it stands now I have everything working to fully implement basic functionality except for the "UP" key previous command scrolling feature.

How might something like this be implemented? I realize it may be as simple as retaining an array of `char*` to the input strings, but how do we capture "UP" key button presses?

Once we have the above implemented, how can you write to stdout without making it permanent? That is, when you press "UP" again then it erases what was previously written with another command.

Comment: @true, the shell I am implementing is standalone so it doesn't have anything to do with any other production shell, like bash.

Comment: Look at linenoise: https://github.com/antirez/linenoise. It does this, is only 1000 loc, and is quite nicely documented.

Comment: are you taking non-buffered character-by-character input from STDIN? this is not the default behavior in most C implementations, but it is quite probable if you are implementing a command-line interface, and would change the answer to this question dramatically.

Answer (score 3):

A practical way to implement the <kbd>up</kbd> key would be to use [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library (and its `history` sub-library). BTW, some shells actually do use GNU readline (it is under GPL license). And you'll get line edition also. And you could implement completion with the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, etc.

There are other ways, like using `ncurses` or `termcap` etc... Or emitting [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) on a raw terminal. See also [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) & [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html)...

BTW, most Linux shells are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html), so you could study their source code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using non-buffered character-by-character input directly from STDIN (which means, among other things, control characters such as CTRL+C are not handled automatically), then you will be reading byte-by-byte. Arrow keys, unlike ASCII symbols, put multiple bytes on STDIN because they are [excape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). These bytes differ from system to system. The easiest way to determine the escape sequence on your system is to execute the `cat` command with no arguments, then hit the arrow keys. Something like `^[[A` will be displayed, you will need to convert that sequence from ASCII to hex bytes.

Once you've done that, you can read the bytes one at a time with `get_char()`, just like you're probably already doing in your input function anyway.